# C++ tutorial or example of Redis for fastest insert

Tags: c++, redis

Does anyone have any reference resources that show the fastest way to insert market data into a Redis Server? I am looking at data sets in the millions so I am trying to find some good coding examples to achieve this in C++ using a library like credis or hiredis. Does anyone have an end to end tutorial or set of source code examples of this? I seem to only find examples of simple connection testing or simple insertions. 
Thanks

Comment: Well, bulk insert is probably the fastest, and still relatively simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to insert data into Redis is probably to use the pipe mode of the redis-cli client. More information here: http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert

Now if you are interested in a C API to efficiently send many queries to Redis, look no further than Hiredis. Hiredis is up-to-date and maintained by Redis authors. I suggest to use it over the other options, even in a C++ context.

Here is a simple pipelining example:
https://gist.github.com/1893378

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for helping understand the power of this Redis.

Answer (score 1):

a redis client written in C++ is [redis-cplusplus-client](https://github.com/mrpi/redis-cplusplus-client), on github repo, depends on c++ boost library.